# How to read Java properties file from a JAAS LoginModule

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, properties, jaas

I'd like to read a properties file in my applications WEB-INF folder or my tomcat/apache server from a JAAS loginModule.  But I'm not understanding how to properly refer to the location from the LoginModule, in a host name independent manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the catalina.base system property:

```
File confDir = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "conf");
File confFile = new File(confDir, "myprops.properties");
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(confFile);
try {
    props.load(in);
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```